# Online version of the Louvre museum

Tags: online-resources, planning, paris, museums, the-louvre

I know that some museums offer online tours of their exhibits, and you can easy "navigate" from one place to another and view the exhibitions. Is there any such online tour for the Louvre (museum in Paris)? I wanted to 'virtually' visit and decide which exhibitions to see when I go there.

Comment: Is this really travel related? Maybe you can reword it to make it more travel related.

Comment: @hippietrail I'm interested in this because I'm going to visit Paris, and want to get some info about museums there. Is it ok?

Comment: @VMAth: I think it's good. Maybe try to get some of that wording in to the question. I'll add the [tag:planning] tag too which seems appropriate.

Comment: @hippietrail Ok, I'll update the question

Comment: Rephrased this to make it 'more' on-topic.

Comment: @VMAtm: Ankur and I have been discussing in chat if it's on-topic even now but neither of us want to vote to close. Drop in if you wish.

Comment: @hippietrail Can't use the chat right now. If the community say this is offtopic, I'll vote to close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Louvre's website throws up two options which come close:

- [Virtual Tours](http://www.louvre.fr/en/visites-en-ligne): Updated for 2016. Requires QuickTime plugin. Shows pans of specific exhibits and areas.
- [3D Tours](http://www.louvre.fr/llv/dossiers/liste_ei.jsp?bmLocale=en): Requires a special 3D plugin (Virtools) and has 3D recreations of exhibits. Not particularly impressive.

Answer (score 6):

I think the biggest cross-gallery "virtual tour" at the moment is the one that Google did, [Google Art Project](http://www.googleartproject.com/). It covers 17 leading world art galleries, but alas the Louvre isn't currently one of them...

If you look at their [FAQ](http://www.googleartproject.com/c/faq) it lists the museums currently available, such as the National Gallery in London and MoMA in New York. Be warned though, you can easily spend hours browsing on it, even without the Louvre's collections!

In terms of planning a visit to the Louvre (assuming Google Art hasn't persuaded you to go elsewhere!), the Louvre website does provide [an interactive floorplan](http://www.louvre.fr/llv/pratique/plan.jsp?bmLocale=en) which could be handy in deciding where inside to go.

Comment: Art Project is a really nice site! Thanks for recommending it.